# File download via Webapi controller - handling errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an application that provides some links for users to download files.
The page itself is served up by an MVC controller but the links are pointing to a WebAPI controller running on a separate domain.

(I would have preferred same domain but for various reasons it has to be a separate project and it will run on a separate domain. I don't think CORS is part of the issue anyway as this is not using XHR, but I mention it just in case).

So in development, the main MVC project is `http://localhost:56626/Reports/`

And the links on the page might look like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:51288/ReportDownload?ID=12345">Report 12345</a>
```

where port 51288 is hosting the Web API.

The WebAPI controller uses ReportID to locate a file, and write its contents into the response stream, setting the disposition as an attachment:

```
//security.permission  checks and scaffolding/database interaction
//left out for clarity
 try
 {
    string filename = @"C:\ReportFiles\TestReport.csv";
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
    var disp = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    disp.FileName = "TestReport.csv";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = disp;
    return result;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //how to return a response that won't redirect on error?
}
```

By doing this the user can then click on the link and without any redirection, the user gets prompted to save or open the file, which is what I want; they stay on the original page with the links and just get an Open/Save dialog from the browser.

*The problem arises when something goes wrong in the Web API controller - either an exception or some internal logic condition that means the file cannot be downloaded.*

- In this case when clicking the link, the download doesn't happen (obviously) and they get taken to the target URL instead i.e `http://localhost:51288/api/ReportDownload?ReportID=12345` which is not desirable for my requirements.
- I would much rather be able to catch the error somehow on the client-side by returning for e.g. HTTP 500 in the response, and just display a message to the user that the download failed.

Now to be honest, I don't even understand how the browser can do the "in place" File/Save dialog in the first place:

- I always thought if you click a link that has no explicit `target` attribute,the browser would just open the new request in your current tab i.e it's just another GET request to the target URL, but it seems this is not the case
- The browser seems to be doing a hidden background fetch of the target URL in this case (same behaviour in FF,Chrome and IE) which I cannot even see in the F12 tools.
- The F12 Network log shows no activity at all except in the specific case where the response has NOT been setup as `Content-Disposition: attachment` i.e an error -only in this case do I see the (failed) HTTP GET being logged in the Network request list.

I suppose I could just catch any exception in the controller and send back a dummy file called "Error.csv" with contents "Ha Ha Nope!" or something similar, but that would be a last resort...any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user clicks on the link, the browser will follow it - then depending on the response headers and browser configuration, it'll either show the file dialog or render directly - you can't really change that behavior (apart from using preventDefault when the link is clicked, which kind of defeats the purpose).

I'd suggest taking a closer look at http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/ which lets you do something like this:

```
$.fileDownload('some/file/url')
    .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Then you could bind the download action using jQuery.

Comment: Nice one - not sure how I missed that in my initial googling...I'll try it,and let you know.

Comment: Just FYI, that worked pretty much perfectly, thanks a million.